# Django form not getting the select field selection. Dropdown dependant

Tags: django, search, django-views, django-forms, django-queryset

I have a very complex way in which I ask a database within my own project for the State, County and Neighborhood through Ajax, with the help of the forms.py, now, I have it for registering a room (which is related to these locations), and it goes through a CreateView, with this one I have no issues, but, when wanting to make a queryset to perform a search of my rooms and their respective locations, it just seems like it´s not picking up what is selected on the field, this I know because I asked it to print the request and it prints 'None', here is my code:

models.py

```
class PostRoom(models.Model):
  
  author = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,default=1,related_name='room_author')
  colonia = models.ForeignKey(Colonia, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
  cp = models.ForeignKey(CP, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
  municipio = models.ForeignKey(Municipio, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
  estado = models.ForeignKey(Estado, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
```

the CreateView where everything works perfectly:

```
class RoomSubmitCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
  model = PostRoom
  form_class = PostRoomForm

  def form_valid(self, form):
    form.instance.author = self.request.user
    return super().form_valid(form)
```

The ajax code through which I send the selected fields to my location.views.py:

```
<script>
$("#id_estado").change(function () {
  var url = $("#roomForm").attr("load-municipios");  // get the url of the `load_cities` view
  var estadoId = $(this).val();  // get the selected country ID from the HTML input

  $.ajax({                       // initialize an AJAX request
    url: url,                    // set the url of the request (= localhost:8000/hr/ajax/load-cities/)
    data: {
      'estado': estadoId       // add the country id to the GET parameters
    },
    success: function (data) {   // `data` is the return of the `load_cities` view functionlog
    console.log(data);
      $("#id_municipio").html(data);  // replace the contents of the city input with the data that came from the server
    }
  });

});
```

```
<script>
$("#id_municipio").change(function () {
  var url = $("#roomForm").attr("load-colonias");  // get the url of the `load_cities` view
  var municipioId = $(this).val();  // get the selected country ID from the HTML input

  $.ajax({                       // initialize an AJAX request
    url: url,                    // set the url of the request (= localhost:8000/hr/ajax/load-cities/)
    data: {
      'municipio': municipioId       // add the country id to the GET parameters
    },
    success: function (data) {   // `data` is the return of the `load_cities` view functionlog
    console.log(data);
      $("#id_colonia").html(data);  // replace the contents of the city input with the data that came from the server
    }
  });

});
```

Now, where things don't work.
my forms.py for search:

```
class RoomSearch(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = PostRoom
    fields = ('estado',
              'municipio',
              'colonia')

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['municipio'].queryset = Municipio.objects.none()
    self.fields['colonia'].queryset = Colonia.objects.none()

    if 'estado' in self.data:
        try:
            estado_id = int(self.data.get('estado'))
            self.fields['municipio'].queryset = Municipio.objects.filter(estado_id=estado_id).order_by('municipio')
        except (ValueError, TypeError):
            pass  # invalid input from the client; ignore and fallback to empty City queryset
    elif self.instance.pk:
        self.fields['municipio'].queryset = self.instance.estado.municipio_set.order_by('municipio')

    if 'municipio' in self.data:
        try:
            municipio_id = int(self.data.get('municipio'))
            self.fields['colonia'].queryset = Colonia.objects.filter(municipio_id=municipio_id).order_by('colonia')
        except (ValueError, TypeError):
            pass  # invalid input from the client; ignore and fallback to empty City queryset
    elif self.instance.pk:
        self.fields['colonia'].queryset = self.instance.municipio.colonia_set.order_by('colonia')
```

and my search.views.py:

```
def room_results(request):
form = RoomSearch(request.GET or None)
context = {
    "form": form,
}
print ("ESTADO:",form['estado'].value())
print ("MUNICIPIO:",form['municipio'].value())
print ("COLONIA:",form['colonia'].value())
if request.method == 'GET':
    print ("SI QUERY")
    queryset = PostRoom.objects.all().filter(
    estado__id__exact=form['estado'].value(),
    municipio__id__exact=form['municipio'].value(),
    colonia__id__exact=form['colonia'].value()
    )
    context = {
    "rooms": queryset,
    "form": form,
}
return render(request, "search/search_room.html",context)
```

No matter what I do, it prints this in the log every time:

```
ESTADO: None
MUNICIPIO: None
COLONIA: None
SI QUERY
```

Btw, where I got know-how to do the weird dependent dropdown list is from https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/01/29/how-to-implement-dependent-or-chained-dropdown-list-with-django.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, AMIGOS, nobody answered (wow, great surprise, never have had any direct help over here), as always, it has a flummsy mistake, in the HTML file I had:

```
<a type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
  <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
</a>
```

And it was supposed to be:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
      <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
</button>
```